# Illustrator : how can I select all the vertexes of the current path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When I have a vertex on a path selected, is there a shortcut to extend the selection to all the vertexes of the path ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you select a vertex on a path with the **Direct Selection Tool**, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click again on the same point to select the path.

Comment: It's worth noting this can also be done while using the **Pen Tool** if you hold `Opt`+`Cmd` (Mac) or `Alt`+`Ctrl` (Windows). Add `Shift` to those if trying to select *multiple* paths.

Answer (score 2):

There is a ‘group selection tool’ under direct selection tool. Use it to select your path. All vertices will be selected.

[image]